# Last read byte time for a file

Tags: file

**Question:**
Is there a way to check last access time for a file an NOT a last opened time for a file?

Lets say I have a file, and I perform following operations

T0: I open a file from a java program.

T1: I keep it opened for long time.

T2: I read some bytes from the already kept open file.

T3: Check the last access time for a file.

---

If I perform a check to understand last time the file was accessed, it provide T0 timestamp.

Is there a way to get information that some read operation were performed on a file on T2.